Most elegant way to 'write' to slice without stdlib (possibly on microcontrollers)
Suppose you have a struct
struct A {
    a: u8,
    b: u16,
    c: u32
}

and you want to output it to a slice like this
impl A {
    pub fn to_buffer(&self, output: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, Error>{
        todo!()
    }
}

but it's gonna run into a microcontroller, so you can't use the std lib and possibly other features. I've been doing like this:
 pub fn to_buffer(&self, output: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, Error>{
       output[0] = self.a;
       output[1..3].copy_from_slice(self.b.to_le_bytes());
       output[3..7].copy_from_slice(self.c.to_le_bytes());
       7
    }

the problem is that this is error prone and also could panic if the slice has not enough space. It's much better if I could do something like
output.write(self.a)?; 
output.write(self.b)?;
output.write(self.c)?

I can do this with a Cursor but I want to do it without the std lib. Also, I need to return the number of bytes written, because the output buffer is possibly pre-allocated into the ROM so it has a much bigger size then needed (worst case size).
What would be the most elegant way and less error prone?

You can create your own Write, it's not even hard.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/std/io/impls.rs.html#369-406

What do you mean by "pre-allocated into the ROM"? Your program cannot change a bit in ROM, such space is impossible to write to during run-time.

I'd probably try to duplicate the appoximate interface of fmt::Display and io:Write, in a way that's more specific to your requirement. So, something like this:
use core::{slice, cmp};

/// Trait for things that can be *written to*.
trait Output {
    type Error;

    fn write_bytes(&mut self, bytes: &[u8]) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
}

impl Output for &mut [u8] {
    // Feel free to use your own error type if you want more useful
    // error information
    type Error = (); 

    fn write_bytes(&mut self, bytes: &[u8]) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        let i = cmp::min(self.len(), bytes.len());
        self[..i].copy_from_slice(&bytes[..i]);
        *self = &mut self[i..];

        if bytes.len() <= i {
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(())
        }
    }
}

/// Trait for things that can be written to `Output`.
trait Writeable {
    fn write_to_output<O>(&self, output: &mut O) -> Result<(), O::Error>
        where O: Output;
}

impl Writeable for u8 {
    fn write_to_output<O>(&self, output: &mut O) -> Result<(), O::Error>
        where O: Output
    {
        output.write_bytes(slice::from_ref(self))
    }
}

// If you have a lot of integer types you want to support, consider
// using a macro to implement this trait for all of them

impl Writeable for u16 {
    fn write_to_output<O>(&self, output: &mut O) -> Result<(), O::Error>
        where O: Output
    {
        output.write_bytes(&self.to_le_bytes())
    }
}

impl Writeable for u32 {
    fn write_to_output<O>(&self, output: &mut O) -> Result<(), O::Error>
        where O: Output
    {
        output.write_bytes(&self.to_le_bytes())
    }
}

// If you're writing a lot of traits like this, with a long sequence
// of sequential writes, I'd consider writing a macro to handle that,
// too

impl Writeable for A {
    fn write_to_output<O>(&self, output: &mut O) -> Result<(), O::Error>
        where O: Output
    {
        self.a.write_to_output(output)?;
        self.b.write_to_output(output)?;
        self.c.write_to_output(output)
    }
}

This version doesn't return the number of written bytes; it instead assumes you can compute it yourself, if needed, based on the length of the slice after all of the writes conclude.
As it happens, I use precisely this pattern as a way to abstract over str and [u8] in the Redis Protocol crate I wrote: Output, Writeable. One neat thing I did there was add a write_fmt method, which gives you "for free" integration with the write! macro, if that's something you're interested in. This pattern also enables the creation of adapters, which can make certain kinds of correctness checking more straightforward (for instance, suppose you wanted an Output that never accepts \0 bytes).
